# How to read ami id dynamically from aws using cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am automating the cloudformation template by reading latest ami id from the corresponding region. I was able to achieve this by using terraform.

In terraform, we have data sources to query and filter the aws ami-id. similarly do we have any sources in cloudformation to query and filter the private aws ami-id?

In terraform, we can get the ami id using the below

```
data "aws_ami" "example" {
  executable_users = ["self"]
  most_recent      = true
  name_regex       = "^myami-\\d{3}"
  owners           = ["self"]

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["myami-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "root-device-type"
    values = ["ebs"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
}
```

Whereas, could anyone help me to do the same using cloudformation template?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

*This walkthrough shows you how to create a custom resource and associate a Lambda function with it to look up AMI IDs.*

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html

Comment: I have to read the two ami ids from one lambda function using cloudformation. Is there any way to read the two different ami ids from lambda function in cloudformation?